# Flutter : deeplink not work in my flutter app chat screen link click also any time open preview.page.link page

Tags: flutter, dart, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

Here i attached image for when i click deeplink then redirect move this screen
i have no idea how to redirect this link
please help me for this issue

also
**android is working fine**

[image]

Comment: this looks normal, deep links on ios will always show this page.

Comment: But how to slove it

Comment: What do you mean? This is the intended outcome. It's not an error. When the User clicks OPEN, it will open your app.

Comment: this not open in safari 
step1- first click in open button then redirect to google 
step2 -same page on in google when click open button and then click top left button done 

then move deeplink page

Comment: also i have open in other social media in same link then working properly
sp i don't have idea how is same open in different different

Comment: You can test your links by appending ?d=1 to the end of it. For example preview.page.link/your_link_name?d=1

Comment: I already used it 
https://spot1app.page.link/PlaceDetailsScreen?id=298